# Execute code only if it's in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a html5/js extension for chrome and i want to make it available online as classic web page.

In my js code i have :

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(arrayOfTabs) {
    var activeTab = arrayOfTabs[0];
    var activeTabId = arrayOfTabs[0].url;
    $scope.myForm.url = activeTabId;
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

how to prevent the error "query is undefined" and make code functional as a web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution

```
/* chrome things */
var isExtension = chrome.tabs;
if (isExtension !== undefined) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(arrayOfTabs) {
        var activeTab = arrayOfTabs[0];
        var activeTabId = arrayOfTabs[0].url;
        $scope.myForm.url = activeTabId;
        $scope.$apply();
    });
} else {
    $scope.myForm.url = "test";
}
```